# Want to add variables in span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have static text **Net Salary**. Now I want to add Salary in digital and  verbal form how can I add them in html

**html**

```
<div id="net_table" class="col-md-12">
     <p id="net_sum" class="net-salary-txt"><strong>Net Salary: </strong><span id="digits"></span><span id="words"></span>
    </p> 
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
//Total Salary
$('#net_table').each(function(){

    var income_total=($('#income_total').text()||0);
    var deduction_total=($('#deduction_total').text()||0);

    var sum = parseInt(income_total) + parseInt(deduction_total);
    var numToWords=numToWords(sum);

    var digits = document.getElementById("digits");
    var words = document.getElementById("words");

    digits.appendChild(sum);
    words.appendChild(numToWords);
});
```

Comment: What is a *digital and verbal* form ? What is your code doing now ? What is the desired output ? What error do you have ?

Comment: Don't use id for repeater element. Use class instead

Comment: Means number in digits and words. For example output is 298. Digits must show 298 and words should show Two hundred ninety eight only

Comment: How to adjust two variables using same classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "appendChild"

```
 digits.innerHTML = sum;
 words.innerHTML = numToWords;
```

Comment: You also seam to use the same name for the numToWords function and the variable, could be that it gives an error and thats why its not working

Comment: Ok Iet me check

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For number to word conversion refer this link
[Number to word](http://number%20to%20word)

You may use jquery text() function instead of appendChild

```
$('#digits').text(sum);
$('#words').text(numToWords);
```